# Aws Api gateway cors issue on multiple hits on API resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have been experiencing a rare cors issue in api gateway. Frontend application is calling particular api resouce when user selects a particular range from date picker. So if user continously selects date and calls this api (say around more than 10 times), only on the last hit (10th hit for example), user is facing the cors issue.

[image: cors screenshot]

I am using AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) for building serverless applications. Below is the configuration

Get Request:

```
/v2/myapi:
            get:
              consumes:
              - application/json
              produces:
              - application/json
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: 200 response
                  schema:
                    $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
                  headers:
                    X-Frame-Options:
                      type: "string"
                    Strict-Transport-Security:
                      type: "string"
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                      type: "string"
                    X-Content-Type-Options:
                      type: "string"
                    X-XSS-Protection:
                      type: "string"
              security:
              - lambda_authorizer: []
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                uri:
                  Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:test_myapi/invocations
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: "200"
                    responseParameters:
                      method.response.header.X-Frame-Options: '''DENY'''
                      method.response.header.Strict-Transport-Security: '''max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload'''
                      method.response.header.X-XSS-Protection: '''1'''
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '''*'''
                      method.response.header.X-Content-Type-Options: '''nosniff'''
```

Options

options:

```
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        "200":
          description: 200 response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: "string"
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: "string"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: '''DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'''
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '''Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'''
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '''*'''
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        type: "mock"
```

I have followed the aws guidelines https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html but still not sure why this random cors issue comes. I am not enabling Cors from aws console, since we are deploying only through saml.yaml file.

For initial requests there will be no issue. So I am wondering is there any limit or some other issues here.

Any help would be really appreciated as I am having hard time to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those of who are struggling a bit on this can do a check on the below.

I Checked the API Gateway logs and got the below error.

```
Gateway response type: WAF_FILTERED with status code: 403
WafFilteredException Forbidden:
```

Web Application Firewall (WAF) has been enabled and WAF blocks the request when we continously hitting same api for sometimes.  It was configured as 100 request per 5 min.
So if anyone face the issue, you can check how you have configured the WAF and increase according to your needs.

Resource:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-awswaf.html